# Streaming with nintendo (3)DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds, streaming

I Recently found a [streamer on twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/thejustinflynn/c/2542998) that was streaming his Nintendo DS mario Kart over the internet. Now as a streamer myself I know how PC streaming works, but how exactly is it possible to stream from a nintendo ds? I couldn't find any Xsplit or similar in the nintendo app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this streamers [FAQ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9jgcjWFgw9SUszcU1pZWNGQ2c/edit?usp=sharing), he uses a capture card and OBS (open broadcasting software).

A 3DS game capture card can be found [here](http://3dscapture.com/)